# Is there any time limit on Assists?

Tags: mass-effect-3

I've noticed that after I die in a round, when I'm revived I'll get the assists I earned while I was dead. Sometimes I get several.

Is there any time limit after which I lose "assist" status, or if I deal 50 XP's worth of damage to a target, will I ALWAYS get that XP once the target dies?

Comment: My initial guess is "yes" but I'm not sure how to prove it.

Comment: @SteveV. if there is it's *very* long, I've gotten assists after being dead will over a minute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no time limit. Merely using a power or dealing damage to an enemy will grant you an assist, no matter how long it has been.